# Material dark with light actionbar

Tags: android, material-design

I want to have dark app with actionbar with light colors.

So I made this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LightActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="LightActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar">
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. The app is dark, only the status bar has dark primary color.